# highcharts x-axis date issue

Tags: highcharts, ionic3

i'm trying to show dates on x-axis. all dates are showing one day off. here is my dates to be shown 4/23/2017, 4/30/2017, 5/7/2017, 5/14/2017,05/21/2017,06/04/2017 in x-axis. and what it's showing is this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGAcg.png). it's show date which is not there or near (5/29/2017) which is overlapping with other. this is my code`xAxis: { tickAmount: 5,
  type: 'datetime',
  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    day: '%m/%d/%Y',
                    week: '%m/%d/%Y',
                    month: '%m/%d/%Y',
                 },
                 labels: {
                style: {
                    fontFamily : "Open Sans"
                },
                } 
            },
            time: {useUTC: false },`

Comment: anyone faced this kind of problem before?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you've `time.useUTC = true` (default option). Change it to false and it should work as expected.

**Code:**

```
var data = [
  ['4 / 23 / 2017', 1], // [date, value]
  ['4 / 30 / 2017', 2],
  ['5 / 7 / 2017', 4],
  ['5 / 14 / 2017', 2],
  ['05 / 21 / 2017', 3],
  ['06 / 04 / 2017', 5]
];

Highcharts.chart('container', {

  xAxis: {
    tickAmount: 5,
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      day: '%m/%d/%Y',
      week: '%m/%d/%Y',
      month: '%m/%d/%Y',
    },
    labels: {
      style: {
        fontFamily: "Open Sans"
      },
    }
  },
  time: {
    useUTC: false
  },

  series: [{
    data: data.map(elem => {
        elem[0] = new Date(elem[0]).getTime();
      return elem;
    })
  }]
});
```

**API:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.useUTC

**Demo:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cm4azod0

Comment: we passed different dates and x-axis showing different dates. i used global also none of the global or time giving me the correct dates on x-axis.

Comment: this is my exact data  [1492920000000, 300]
1: (2) [1493524800000, 100]
2: (2) [1494129600000, 300]
3: (2) [1494734400000, 200]
4: (2) [1495339200000, 150]
5: (2) [1496548800000, 0]

Comment: x-axis is not showing the same dates as data. If you want to set them as you like you can use `xAxis.tickPositions` or `xAxis.tickPositioner`. Check api: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions

Comment: hi chmiel. the same chart is not working if i have only one date. i have only 04/23/2017. its show 04:00:00.000

Comment: Could you prepare a demo with this issue?